# Error: Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

A piece of my code:

```
                var folder = CreateFolder(ctx.Web, "PSA Repository", "/xxxxxx/");

                //Permissions
                folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
                var roleDefinition = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);
                var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);
                roleBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal p = GetPrincipal("xxx", ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                RoleAssignment oRoleAssignment = folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(p, roleBindings);

                folder.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // The error is here
```

I want to add permissions to the user xxx to the folder xxxxxx, can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that CSOM does not like the new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection being instaniated, calling ExecuteQuery(), and then calling ExecuteQuery() again after the RoleDefinitionBindingCollection is added to the folder. The same problem has affected me. I would do something like this:

```
folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(p, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { roleDefintion });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Robert is right.

```
folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(user, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { roleDefintion });
```