# Error "Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection`" when i try to grant folders unique permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code inside my remote event receiver to grant a folder unique permissions:-

```
    RoleDefinition readerDef = context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);
    RoleDefinitionBindingCollection readOnlyBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context);
    readOnlyBinding.Add(readerDef);

    List<Principal> usersToGrantRead = new List<Principal>();
    context.Load(context.Web, w => w.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, w =>                                                            
    w.RoleAssignments.Include(roleAssigned => roleAssigned.Member.Title));

                  foreach (RoleAssignment r in listItem.RoleAssignments)
                      {
                         usersToGrantRead.Add(r.Member);
                      }
    listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false); 
    context.ExecuteQuery();

                 foreach (Principal p in usersToGrantRead)
                      {
                         listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(p,readOnlyBinding);
                      }
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

but i am getting this error `Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection` on the last line `context.ExecuteQuery();`

Comment: Try adding RoleAssignments in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145989/error-cannot-add-a-role-assignment-with-empty-role-definition-binding-collectio) way. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap your link fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `RoleAssignments` in this way:

```
folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(p, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { roleDefintion });
```

**Source**:

[Error: Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145989/error-cannot-add-a-role-assignment-with-empty-role-definition-binding-collectio).